# Defining WordNetError

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, senti-wordnet

I have a list of terms in a sentence with sentiwordnet parts-of-speech, which I am attempting to sum over to find the net sentiment:

```
from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn, wordnet

score = 0            
        for term in terms:
            try:
                term = swn.senti_synset(term)
            except WordNetError:
                pass
            score += term.pos_score() - term.neg_score()
```

Prior to adding the exception, I was getting WordNetError due to a particular synset not being present in the dict. Having now added the exception, I am receiving this error:

```
NameError: name 'WordNetError' is not defined
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Replace `WordNetError` by `wordnet.WordNetError`. And please, use a search engine next time, it's literally the first link.

Comment: @dhke rude! I did and your solution doesn't work

Comment: AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'WordNetError'

Comment: @user30588703 My bad, yes it's in `nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet`. And yes, it can be considered rude to expect a little more research.

Answer (score 7):

```
from nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet import WordNetError
```

Had to import WordNetError